# Why CSS nesting sibling combinator doesn't apply correctly in following example?

Tags: css, nested, siblings

```
<div class='splash yellow'>
  <span>Yellow</span>
</div>
<div class='splash green'>
  <span>Green</span>
</div>
<div class='splash red'>
  <span>Red</span>
</div>
```

```
.splash {
    margin: 15px;
  
    + .red {
        background-color: red;
    }
    + .green {
        background-color: green;
    }
    + .yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8e27qyc9/2/

How come the yellow background isn't applied like red and green in the fiddle example? What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: there is no splash element before yellow

Comment: Are you confusing the space combinator with the + combinator? It isn't showing yellow because the element with class yellow has no immediate predecessor that has class splash. Both the other colors do.

Comment: found it. just gotta put & at the end of the class. Thanks guys!
https://jsfiddle.net/ch7y1zxo/

Answer (score 0):

I confused sibling selector with compound selector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting#concatenation_is_not_possible

Solution:

```
.splash {
    margin: 15px;
  
    .red& {
        background-color: red;
    }
    .green& {
        background-color: green;
    }
    .yellow& {
        background-color: yellow;
    }

}
```